# Creating a matrix from a list of simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have a list of `n` simultaneous equations of the form,

```
w A[n] = (K[n,n+1]+K[n-1,n])A[n] - K[n,n+1]A[n+1] - K[n-1,n]A[n-1]
```

Where w is a constant and `K[i,j]` are constants (the order of the indices doesn't actually matter, `K[i,j]=K[j,i]`)

So for some value of `n`, I have a list of `n` equations to solve. I want to know possible values of `w` by solving an eigenvalue problem where the `K` coefficients are represented in a matrix acting on the vector `A` (with components `A[1],A[2]`,etc.). So

K(Matrix) A = w A

I can produce the matrix by hand for low values of n but I would like to have Mathematica generate a matrix using the function for any value of `n`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Check `CoefficientArrays`.